# Position sub-menu to right of primary menu with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a very basic menu on my site.

Here's my Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/a41xkr9z/

I'd like to position each sub menu to the right of the main menu so each sub menu is in line vertically with the top of the grey menu.

How do I achieve this with CSS?

```js
$('#menu-primary-menu>li>a').click(function() {
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

```css
#menu-primary-menu>li>ul {
  display: none
}

#menu-primary-menu {
    background-color:#eee;
    width:200px;
}

#menu-primary-menu ul {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0;
    left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-primary-menu-container">
  <ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-27"><a href="#">Projects</a>
      <ul>
        <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-26"><a href="/category/projects/residential/">Residential</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-24"><a href="/category/projects/private/">Private</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
      
      
    <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-27"><a href="#">More Projects</a>
      <ul>
        <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-26"><a href="/category/projects/residential/">Residential</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-24"><a href="/category/projects/private/">Private</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
      
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your css like this. This will position sub-menu vertically with parent menu.

**[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/a41xkr9z/2/)**

```
#menu-primary-menu{position:relative;}  /*--Added--*/
#menu-primary-menu ul {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    /*---margin-top: 0;---- Removed*/
    top:0;  /*--Added--*/
    left: 250px;
}
```

Comment: Excellent stuff!! That worked a treat. Now I just need to fix that pesky js error where it shows 2 menus at one time :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `top: 0` to your `#menu-primary-menu` element

```js
$('#menu-primary-menu>li>a').click(function() {
     $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

```css
#menu-primary-menu>li>ul {
    display: none
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu-primary-menu {
    position: relative;
    background-color:#eee;
    width:200px;
}

#menu-primary-menu ul {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-primary-menu-container">
  <ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-27"><a href="#">Projects</a>
      <ul>
        <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-26"><a href="/category/projects/residential/">Residential</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-24"><a href="/category/projects/private/">Private</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-27"><a href="#">More Projects</a>
      <ul>
        <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-26"><a href="/category/projects/residential/">Residential</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-24"><a href="/category/projects/private/">Private</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>   
  </ul>
</div>
```